# Java app won't start after updating

Tags: raspbian, java

After updating my raspberry (Raspbian) and everything on it including java my java application won't start anymore, does anyone know what these crashlog mean and how to solve it or create a workaround?

I updated the PI by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update

java manually from oracle website
the files in /opt/vc/ manually from [raspberrypi/firmware][1]
```

I included the log report found in /opt/vc/lib/

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000, pid=2296, tid=2908673136
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_06-b23) (build 1.8.0_06-b23)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.6-b23 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/vc/lib/core or core.2296
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x022da180):  JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2308, stack(0xad59e000,0xad5ee000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000

Registers:
  r0  = 0x00000000
  r1  = 0x00000000
  r2  = 0x00000184
  r3  = 0x00000000
  r4  = 0x00000000
  r5  = 0xad59d7f4
  r6  = 0xad5ec5e8
  r7  = 0x023624e0
  r8  = 0xad5ec5e8
  r9  = 0xae0cb8c8
  r10 = 0x022da180
  fp  = 0xad5ec454
  r12 = 0xad590728
  sp  = 0xad5ec450
  lr  = 0xad4a08e8
  pc  = 0x00000000
  cpsr = 0x60000010

Top of Stack: (sp=0xad5ec450)
0xad5ec450:   ad5ec45c ad590748 ad5ec55c ad590224
<removed to save body space>

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000)
0xffffffe0:   

Register to memory mapping:

  r0  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r1  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r2  = 0x00000184
0x00000184 is an unknown value

  r3  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r4  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value

  r5  = 0xad59d7f4
0xad59d7f4: <offset 0x127f4> in /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so at 0xad58b000

  r6  = 0xad5ec5e8
0xad5ec5e8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x022da180

  r7  = 0x023624e0
0x023624e0 is an unknown value

  r8  = 0xad5ec5e8
0xad5ec5e8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x022da180

  r9  = 0xae0cb8c8
0xae0cb8c8 is an unknown value

  r10 = 0x022da180
0x022da180 is a thread

  fp  = 0xad5ec454
0xad5ec454 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x022da180

  r12 = 0xad590728
0xad590728: wr_eglGetDisplay+0 in /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so at 0xad58b000

  sp  = 0xad5ec450
0xad5ec450 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x022da180

  lr  = 0xad4a08e8
0xad4a08e8: util_wr_eglGetDisplay+0x18 in /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/liblens_porting.so at 0xad49f000

  pc  = 0x00000000
0x00000000 is an unknown value



Stack: [0xad59e000,0xad5ee000],  sp=0xad5ec450,  free space=313k
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.prism.es2.EGLFBGLFactory.nInitialize([I)J+0
j  com.sun.prism.es2.EGLFBGLFactory.initialize(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLPixelFormat$Attributes;)Z+73
j  com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>()V+51
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+8
j  com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline()Lcom/sun/prism/GraphicsPipeline;+191
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init()V+0
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+1
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x022da180 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2308, stack(0xad59e000,0xad5ee000)]
  0x02008388 JavaThread "JavaFX-Launcher" [_thread_blocked, id=2305, stack(0xad61f000,0xad66f000)]
  0x01e5b808 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2303, stack(0xad77d000,0xad7cd000)]
  0x01e566b0 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2302, stack(0xad7cd000,0xad84d000)]
  0x01e55218 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2301, stack(0xad84d000,0xad89d000)]
  0x01e33b70 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2300, stack(0xada15000,0xada65000)]
  0x01e32770 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2299, stack(0xada65000,0xadab5000)]
  0x01dd93e8 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=2297, stack(0xb6396000,0xb63e6000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01e2e950 VMThread [stack: 0xadab5000,0xadb35000] [id=2298]
  0x01de20a8 WatcherThread [stack: 0xad6fd000,0xad77d000] [id=2304]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 1362K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,  68% used [0xae200000, 0xae334830, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae400000, 0xae400000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 1563K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  38% used [0xb0200000, 0xb0386db0, 0xb0386e00, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 3158K, capacity 3210K, committed 3224K, reserved 4400K

Card table byte_map: [0xb4229000,0xb425a000] byte_map_base: 0xb3cb8000

Polling page: 0xb6f92000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=823Kb max_used=823Kb free=31944Kb
 bounds [0xb42da000, 0xb43aa000, 0xb62da000]
 total_blobs=323 nmethods=142 adapters=110
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 6.932 Thread 0x01e566b0  138             sun.util.calendar.CalendarDate::getMonth (5 bytes)
Event: 6.933 Thread 0x01e566b0 nmethod 138 0xb43a7308 code [0xb43a73f0, 0xb43a7478]
Event: 6.934 Thread 0x01e566b0  139             sun.util.calendar.CalendarDate::setNormalized (6 bytes)
Event: 6.935 Thread 0x01e566b0 nmethod 139 0xb43a74c8 code [0xb43a75b0, 0xb43a7638]
Event: 6.995 Thread 0x01e566b0  140             java.net.URL::getFile (5 bytes)
Event: 6.996 Thread 0x01e566b0 nmethod 140 0xb43a7688 code [0xb43a7770, 0xb43a77f8]
Event: 7.058 Thread 0x01e566b0  141             java.lang.System::getSecurityManager (4 bytes)
Event: 7.059 Thread 0x01e566b0 nmethod 141 0xb43a7848 code [0xb43a7930, 0xb43a79b8]
Event: 7.161 Thread 0x01e566b0  142             java.lang.String::endsWith (17 bytes)
Event: 7.163 Thread 0x01e566b0 nmethod 142 0xb43a7a08 code [0xb43a7b00, 0xb43a7bb4]

GC Heap History (6 events):
Event: 2.178 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 1787K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,  99% used [0xae200000, 0xae3becf0, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K,   0% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae3e0000, 0xae400000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 0K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,   0% used [0xb0200000, 0xb0200000, 0xb0200200, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2023K, capacity 2402K, committed 2456K, reserved 4400K
Event: 2.208 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 128K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,   0% used [0xae200000, 0xae200000, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae400000, 0xae400000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 622K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  15% used [0xb0200000, 0xb029b948, 0xb029ba00, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2023K, capacity 2402K, committed 2456K, reserved 4400K
}
Event: 5.647 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 1862K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,  96% used [0xae200000, 0xae3b1998, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae400000, 0xae400000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 622K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  15% used [0xb0200000, 0xb029b948, 0xb029ba00, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2741K, capacity 2794K, committed 2840K, reserved 4400K
Event: 5.677 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 128K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,   0% used [0xae200000, 0xae200000, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000, 0xae3e0000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae3e0000, 0xae400000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 1188K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  29% used [0xb0200000, 0xb03293c8, 0xb0329400, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2741K, capacity 2794K, committed 2840K, reserved 4400K
}
Event: 6.574 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 1910K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,  99% used [0xae200000, 0xae3bd820, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000, 0xae3e0000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae3e0000, 0xae400000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 1188K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  29% used [0xb0200000, 0xb03293c8, 0xb0329400, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2956K, capacity 3018K, committed 3096K, reserved 4400K
Event: 6.599 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 1920K, used 128K [0xae200000, 0xae400000, 0xb0200000)
  eden space 1792K,   0% used [0xae200000, 0xae200000, 0xae3c0000)
  from space 128K, 100% used [0xae3e0000, 0xae400000, 0xae400000)
  to   space 128K,   0% used [0xae3c0000, 0xae3c0000, 0xae3e0000)
 tenured generation   total 4096K, used 1563K [0xb0200000, 0xb0600000, 0xb4200000)
   the space 4096K,  38% used [0xb0200000, 0xb0386db0, 0xb0386e00, 0xb0600000)
 Metaspace       used 2956K, capacity 3018K, committed 3096K, reserved 4400K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.538 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2a2ab0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.785 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2bda78) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.785 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2bdc28) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.801 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2bf5c0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.804 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2bf770) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.832 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2c2458) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.854 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2cba90) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.862 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2cea78) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 1.879 Thread 0x01dd93e8 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0xae2d2140) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 5.270 Thread 0x02008388 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0xae2d5698) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-glinux-arm-vfp-hflt/jdk8u6/612/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 1169]

Events (10 events):
Event: 7.117 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/GLDrawable
Event: 7.117 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/GLDrawable done
Event: 7.125 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLDrawable
Event: 7.125 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLDrawable done
Event: 7.135 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/GLContext
Event: 7.135 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/GLContext done
Event: 7.151 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLContext
Event: 7.151 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLContext done
Event: 7.160 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLPixelFormat
Event: 7.160 loading class com/sun/prism/es2/EGLFBGLPixelFormat done


Dynamic libraries:
00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130435     /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
00010000-00011000 rw-p 00000000 b3:02 130435     /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
01dd3000-02377000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
ad49f000-ad4a7000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130583     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/liblens_porting.so
ad4a7000-ad4ae000 ---p 00008000 b3:02 130583     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/liblens_porting.so
ad4ae000-ad4af000 rw-p 00007000 b3:02 130583     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/liblens_porting.so
ad4af000-ad56e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 269583     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
ad56e000-ad575000 ---p 000bf000 b3:02 269583     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
ad575000-ad579000 r--p 000be000 b3:02 269583     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
ad579000-ad57b000 rw-p 000c2000 b3:02 269583     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
ad57b000-ad581000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad58b000-ad596000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130590     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so
ad596000-ad59d000 ---p 0000b000 b3:02 130590     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so
ad59d000-ad59e000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:02 130590     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so
ad59e000-ad5a1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad5a1000-ad5ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2308]
ad5ee000-ad601000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130586     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnet.so
ad601000-ad608000 ---p 00013000 b3:02 130586     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnet.so
ad608000-ad609000 rw-p 00012000 b3:02 130586     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnet.so
ad609000-ad616000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130587     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnio.so
ad616000-ad61e000 ---p 0000d000 b3:02 130587     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnio.so
ad61e000-ad61f000 rw-p 0000d000 b3:02 130587     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libnio.so
ad61f000-ad622000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad622000-ad66f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2305]
ad66f000-ad6a1000 r--s 0023a000 b3:02 130621     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt-controls.jar
ad6a1000-ad6fd000 r--s 00431000 b3:02 130622     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt-graphics.jar
ad6fd000-ad6fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad6fe000-ad77d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2304]
ad77d000-ad780000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad780000-ad7cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2303]
ad7cd000-ad7d0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad7d0000-ad84d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2302]
ad84d000-ad850000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ad850000-ad89d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2301]
ad89d000-ada15000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 259252     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
ada15000-ada18000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ada18000-ada65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2300]
ada65000-ada68000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ada68000-adab5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2299]
adab5000-adab6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
adab6000-adb84000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2298]
adb84000-add59000 r--s 03c9d000 b3:02 130693     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar
add59000-ae0da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ae0da000-ae200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ae200000-ae400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ae400000-b0200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0200000-b0600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0600000-b4200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4201000-b4205000 r--s 00093000 b3:02 130672     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/jsse.jar
b4205000-b4208000 r--s 00462000 b3:02 268067     /etc/PiPresenter/PiPresenter.jar
b4208000-b420b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b420b000-b4229000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4229000-b422a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b422a000-b4239000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4239000-b423b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b423b000-b4259000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4259000-b425e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b425e000-b42da000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b42da000-b43aa000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b43aa000-b62da000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b62da000-b62f1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130599     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b62f1000-b62f8000 ---p 00017000 b3:02 130599     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b62f8000-b62f9000 rw-p 00016000 b3:02 130599     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libzip.so
b62f9000-b6303000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263326     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
b6303000-b630a000 ---p 0000a000 b3:02 263326     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
b630a000-b630b000 r--p 00009000 b3:02 263326     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
b630b000-b630c000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:02 263326     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.13.so
b630c000-b6315000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 262876     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b6315000-b631c000 ---p 00009000 b3:02 262876     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b631c000-b631d000 r--p 00008000 b3:02 262876     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b631d000-b631e000 rw-p 00009000 b3:02 262876     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_nis-2.13.so
b631e000-b632f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263432     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
b632f000-b6336000 ---p 00011000 b3:02 263432     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
b6336000-b6337000 r--p 00010000 b3:02 263432     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
b6337000-b6338000 rw-p 00011000 b3:02 263432     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnsl-2.13.so
b6338000-b633a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b633a000-b6340000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263473     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6340000-b6347000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 263473     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6347000-b6348000 r--p 00005000 b3:02 263473     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6348000-b6349000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 263473     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_compat-2.13.so
b6349000-b636c000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130568     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b636c000-b6374000 ---p 00023000 b3:02 130568     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b6374000-b6375000 rw-p 00023000 b3:02 130568     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libjava.so
b6375000-b637e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130598     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b637e000-b6386000 ---p 00009000 b3:02 130598     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b6386000-b6387000 rw-p 00009000 b3:02 130598     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/libverify.so
b6387000-b638d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263430     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
b638d000-b6394000 ---p 00006000 b3:02 263430     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
b6394000-b6395000 r--p 00005000 b3:02 263430     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
b6395000-b6396000 rw-p 00006000 b3:02 263430     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.13.so
b6396000-b6399000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6399000-b63e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack:2297]
b63e6000-b644e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 262838     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
b644e000-b6455000 ---p 00068000 b3:02 262838     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
b6455000-b6456000 r--p 00067000 b3:02 262838     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
b6456000-b6457000 rw-p 00068000 b3:02 262838     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.13.so
b6457000-b696f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130547     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b696f000-b6976000 ---p 00518000 b3:02 130547     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b6976000-b69a0000 rw-p 00517000 b3:02 130547     /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so
b69a0000-b6dc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6dc1000-b6de1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 269584     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
b6de1000-b6de8000 ---p 00020000 b3:02 269584     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
b6de8000-b6de9000 rw-p 0001f000 b3:02 269584     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
b6de9000-b6f0c000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263427     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
b6f0c000-b6f13000 ---p 00123000 b3:02 263427     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
b6f13000-b6f15000 r--p 00122000 b3:02 263427     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
b6f15000-b6f16000 rw-p 00124000 b3:02 263427     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.13.so
b6f16000-b6f19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f19000-b6f1b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263431     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
b6f1b000-b6f22000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 263431     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
b6f22000-b6f23000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 263431     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
b6f23000-b6f24000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 263431     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.13.so
b6f24000-b6f38000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 130713     /opt/jdk1.8.0/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f38000-b6f3f000 ---p 00014000 b3:02 130713     /opt/jdk1.8.0/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f3f000-b6f40000 rw-p 00013000 b3:02 130713     /opt/jdk1.8.0/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so
b6f40000-b6f54000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 263225     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
b6f54000-b6f5b000 ---p 00014000 b3:02 263225     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
b6f5b000-b6f5c000 r--p 00013000 b3:02 263225     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
b6f5c000-b6f5d000 rw-p 00014000 b3:02 263225     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.13.so
b6f5d000-b6f5f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f61000-b6f69000 rw-s 00000000 b3:02 130821     /tmp/hsperfdata_root/2296
b6f69000-b6f6b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 266014     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
b6f6b000-b6f72000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 266014     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
b6f72000-b6f73000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 266014     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
b6f73000-b6f90000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 262866     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
b6f92000-b6f93000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f93000-b6f97000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f97000-b6f98000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
b6f98000-b6f99000 r--p 0001d000 b3:02 262866     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
b6f99000-b6f9a000 rw-p 0001e000 b3:02 262866     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so
be91d000-be93e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]

VM Arguments:
java_command: /etc/Appname/Appname.jar
java_class_path (initial): /etc/Appname/Appname.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
USERNAME=root
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x4a4590], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x4a4590], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x3afb74], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x3afb74], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x3afb74], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x3afb74], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x3afc98], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x3b00c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x3b00c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x3b00c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

uname:Linux 3.12.30+ #717 PREEMPT Fri Oct 17 18:46:31 BST 2014 armv6l
libc:glibc 2.13 NPTL 2.13 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 1883, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.10 0.16 0.14

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:         252980 kB
MemFree:          161208 kB
Buffers:            6752 kB
Cached:            46668 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            55840 kB
Inactive:          23300 kB
Active(anon):      25800 kB
Inactive(anon):      480 kB
Active(file):      30040 kB
Inactive(file):    22820 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        511996 kB
SwapFree:         511996 kB
Dirty:               108 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         25744 kB
Mapped:            15080 kB
Shmem:               536 kB
Slab:               4416 kB
SReclaimable:       1448 kB
SUnreclaim:         2968 kB
KernelStack:        1152 kB
PageTables:          796 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      638484 kB
Committed_AS:     122084 kB
VmallocTotal:     761856 kB
VmallocUsed:        5008 kB
VmallocChunk:     495208 kB


CPU:total 1 (ARMv6), vfp

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2708
Revision    : 000e
Serial      : 00000000ad4597bf


Memory: 4k page, physical 252980k(161208k free), swap 511996k(511996k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.6-b23) for linux-arm-vfp-hflt JRE (1.8.0_06-b23), built on Jun 12 2014 07:12:34 by "java_re" with gcc 4.7.2 20120910 (prerelease)

time: Mon Nov 17 16:37:26 2014
elapsed time: 7 seconds
```

The output of the java app contains:

```
Did not find libGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000, pid=2296, tid=2908673136
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_06-b23) (build 1.8.0_06-b23)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.6-b23 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/vc/lib/core or core.2296
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/vc/lib/hs_err_pid2296.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Even though I made sure the libGLESv2.so exists and is updated.

Comment: How did you update the Pi?  Did you use non-standard repositories?

Comment: I used the default repositories, I edited my question.

Comment: Raspbian claims to come with the latest supported Java by default.  Perhaps the one from the Oracle site is too bleeding edge.

Comment: I've installed the 'correct' java version now via apt-get and will do some testing.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything changed in the logs, aside from the java version.

Comment: Outside my experience I'm afraid.  I don't use Java,